# Automatically save input text and files at the same time without submit button

Tags: php, sql, ajax, file, input

I am building a client portal for my web design freelancing business. The goal of this page is to allow clients to type their content and upload a file (image, video, anything) to help me create their home page. The HTML is just a glimpse of what they will be asked to write/upload.

I am having difficulties trying to automatically save `<input type="text" />`, `<textarea></textarea>` and `<input type="file"/>`. Everything works except for `<input type="file"/>` because when they save to the database, `$_POST['file']` is empty. Everything else saves to the database.

This is the JSFiddle where I got the code from: https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/NxQ4A/

`index.php`

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <p class="heading">Heading</p>
        <input name="heading" class="text-input" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="heading">Description</p>
        <textarea name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="heading">Call-To-Action</p>
        <input name="call_to_action" class="text-input" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Add image or video
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

`script.js`

```js
var timeoutId;
$('textarea, .text-input').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    console.log('Textarea Change');

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change    
        saveToDB();
    }, 1000);
});

function saveToDB() {
    console.log('Saving to the db');
    form = $('.form-input');
    var data = $(".form-input").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: data, 
        success: function(data){ 
            console.log('completed');
            $("#message").text("Form has been saved");
            $("#message").addClass("correct");
        }
    });
}

// This is just so we don't go anywhere  
// and still save if you submit the form
$('.form-input').submit(function(e) {
    saveToDB();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

`upload.php`

```php
if(isset($_POST['heading'])) {
    $heading = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["heading"]);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["description"]);
    $cta = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["call_to_action"]);
    $file = $_POST["headline_file"];

  ///see if row exists      
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT project_id FROM project_home_page WHERE project_id = " . $_GET['id'] . ");
        
//if row exists, update it
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

     $sql = "UPDATE project_home_page
             SET headline =  '$heading', description = '$description', call_to_action = '$cta', file = '$file' 
             WHERE project_id = " . $_GET['id'] . ";
            
     $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
            
        } else {
        //if row doesn't exist, insert it
            
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO project_home_page (heading, description, call_to_action, file) 
                     VALUES ($heading', '$description', '$cta', '$file')";
            
            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        }
```